# Google Sheets Script - Copy formulas to values based on column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to be able to replace/paste all or some cells in the row from formulas to values based on a column cell value.

If ColA = "Removed" then all/some cells right copy and paste as value.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), 1);
  var nextCell0 = range.offset(0, 0);
  var nextCell1 = range.offset(0, 1);
  if( nextCell0.getValue() === 'Removed' ) {
    nextCell1.copyTo(nextCell0,{contentsOnly: true});
  }
}
```

This code did not work. Basically, ColA just get copied with exact values from ColB

Screenshot examples:

[Before script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKDh3.png)

[After script execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQqBZ.png)

Multiple Columns to convert from formula to value

[Before Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnGRa.png)

[After script execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOwd6.png)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think will be the range returned by `sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), 1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `nextCell0` is the same range as `range`. And, `nextCell0.getValue()` returns the value from the 1st cell. In this case, it's "A1". And, `nextCell1.copyTo(nextCell0, { contentsOnly: true })` copies from column "B" to column "A". So, when the cell "A1" is "Removed", column "B" is copied to column "A". I thought that this is the reason for your issue.
- `sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), 1)` returns all rows in the sheet. This has already been mentioned in [TheMaster
  's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237031/google-sheets-script-copy-formulas-to-values-based-on-column#comment131066806_74237031). In this case, `sheet.getLastRow()` might be suitable.
- From `I want to be able to replace/paste all or some cells in the row from formulas to values based on a column cell value. If ColA = "Removed" then all/some cells right copy and paste as value.`, unfortunately, I couldn't understand your actual Spreadsheet. So, in this answer, I would like to propose the following patterns.

In order to remove this issue, how about the following modification?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, it supposes that both columns "A" and "B" have the formulas.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2);
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  var values = range.getValues().map(([a], i) => [a == 'Removed' ? formulas[i][1] : formulas[i][0]]);
  range.offset(0, 0, values.length, 1).setFormulas(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, when column "A" is "Removed", the formula of column "B" with the same row is copied to column "A".

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, it supposes that the column "A" and "B" have the values without formulas and the formulas, respectively.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2);
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  var values = range.getValues().map(([a], i) => [a == 'Removed' ? formulas[i][1] : a]);
  range.offset(0, 0, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, when column "A" is "Removed", the formula of column "B" with the same row is copied to column "A".

#### Pattern 3:

In this pattern, it supposes that the column "A" and "B" have the formulas and the values without formulas, respectively.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2);
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  var values = range.getValues().map(([a, b], i) => [a == 'Removed' ? b : formulas[i][0]]);
  range.offset(0, 0, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, when column "A" is "Removed", the value of column "B" with the same row is copied to column "A".

#### Pattern 4:

In this pattern, it supposes that both columns "A" and "B" have values without formulas.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2);
  var values = range.getValues().map(([a, b]) => a == 'Removed' ? [b, b] : [a, b]);
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, when column "A" is "Removed", the value of column "B" with the same row is copied to column "A".

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added:

From your added images, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2);
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  var values = range.getValues().map(([a, b], i) => [a == 'Removed' ? b : formulas[i][1]]);
  range.offset(0, 1, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Answer for your 2nd question:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 5);
  var formulas = range.getFormulas().map(r => r.splice(1));
  var values = range.getValues().map(([a, ...b], i) => a == 'Removed' ? b : formulas[i]);
  range.offset(0, 1, values.length, 4).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tanaike , thankyou so much for all the options. I added two screenshots in the original post to show what i mean, maybe it clears it out. I basically want that if I add "removed" to a cell in ColA that the cell next to it in ColB (which is a formula) gets copied and pasted in itself as a value to remove the formula. Hopefully you can help me out or tell me which is the right pattern of the 4 you suggested. Thankyou again!!!

Comment: @nord_poster Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. From your added images, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: It worked Thank you very much again, and your English was clear! If I could ask one more question I would be very grateful!! What if I wanted ColB:F (F is an example, could be any Col) to go from formula to value? Sorry for the troubles and thanks again!

Comment: @nord_poster About `It worked Thank you very much again`, thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `If I could ask one more question I would be very grateful!! What if I wanted ColB:F (F is an example, could be any Col) to go from formula to value?`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand your new question.

Comment: I added 2 new screenshots. I hope this helps to clear out my question. Once again thank you for your time!!!! Let me know if the screenshots are not clear.

Comment: @nord_poster Thank you for replying. About your 2nd question, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @nord_poster Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: I get this error after 100s `Exception: Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id xxx.
    at removed(Remove Formula:6:41)`
I have currently 30,000 rows and formula stops in row 6888

Comment: @nord_poster About `I get this error after 100s Exception: Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id xxx.     at removed(Remove Formula:6:41) I have currently 30,000 rows and formula stops in row 6888`, I would like to support you. In this case, please post it as a new question by including more information. Because I'm worried that in your current situation, the script might be largely modified. Because my proposed script works fine for several values. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Thank you! I asked a new question.